# An error occurred while doing Spark streaming to read the data from Kafka topic

Tags: windows, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka and Spark. I have pass the messages through the Kafka producer and trying to read in the spark streaming but getting error in main method. The code is given below.

`spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.7 Streaming Example.py`

[image: main method error]

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import json 
import time 


# In[ ]:


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Kafka Spark Demo").getOrCreate()
    sc=spark.sparkContext
    ssc=StreamingContext(sc, 20)
    message = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, topic=['testtopic'], KafkaParams = {"metadata.broker.list": "localhost:9092"})
    data = message.map(lambda x: x[1])
    
    def functordd(rdd):
        try:
            rdd1=rdd.map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
            df = spark.read.json(rdd1)
            df.show()
            sf.createOrReplaceTimeView("Test")
            df1=spark.sql("select iss_position.latitude, iss_position.longitude, message, timestamp from Test")
            
            df1.write.format('csv').mode('append').save("testing")
            
        except:
            pass
        
    data.foreachRDD(functordd)
    sc.stop()
```

Comment: Please show your full error as text, not an image. What command are you using to run the code?

Comment: Note: `pyspark.streaming.kafka` was removed around Spark 2.4; You should be using Structured Streaming if you want to execute sql actions on the Kafka data

Comment: >spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.7 Streaming Example.py I am trying to run the code with this command.

Comment: Put quotes around the py file (or remove them)... And what version of Spark are you using?

Comment: I am using spark 2.4.7 and python version 3.7.9

Answer (score 0):

The command you gave is trying to find/execute a file named `Streaming` and give it an argument named `Example.py`

You need to put quotes around any files with spaces to give them as a single argument

And, you should be using `org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10 ...` (for your respective Spark version; which if you're new to Spark, should be Spark 3) if you are trying to use SQL queries on Kafka data; the streaming dependency is deprecated